# "svn list" looks for "format" file

Tags: xml, apache, svn

I have one svnrepo and two projects in it, which I can list properly with

```
[svn@www1 ~]$ svn list -R file:///svnrepos/testrepo/ <br>
  projA/<br>
  projB/ <br>
  projB/branches/ <br>
  projB/tags/ <br>
  projB/trunk/ <br
  projB/trunk/projA.c <br>
```

When I open `http://myserver.exaple.com/testrepo/projA` with a browser, it says there's no XML style information.

Further, apache error log has these lines:

> (20014)Internal error: Can't open file '/svnrepos/testrepo/projA/format': No such file or directory

The format file *does* exist, but in the location

```
/svnrepos/testrepo/format
```

I believe I have the correct things in httpd.conf

```
<Location /testrepo> 
    DAV svn 
    SVNParentPath /svnrepos/testrepo 
</Location> <br>
```

Why would the system be looking for "format" inside a project?

Thanks for any help.
pnraj

Answer (score 3):

You've configured your HTTP/SVN server incorrectly. The `SVNParentPath` directive is for when you have a whole collection of repositories in a given directory, so you've told the server that `http://myserver.exaple.com/testrepo/projA` maps to a repository at `/svnrepos/testrepo/projA`. Since that doesn't exist, you're getting the error.

To fix this, edit your config to use the `SVNPath` directive instead.